# Sonarqube: Webapp did not start

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, sonarqube, centos7

I'm trying to install and run Sonarqube at the Linux server. Here's the environment:

1. OS: CentOS 7
2. MySQL: MySQL Community Server 5.6.36
3. Sonarqube: 5.6.6

I followed the guide suggested on this site: [Site](https://devopscube.com/setup-and-configure-sonarqube-on-linux/)

There didn't seem to be problems during the installation, but I kept failing to connecting to `http://my-ip-address:9000`. So this time I checked out the log at `/opt/sonarqube/logs/sonar.log` and had the following message.

```
 2017.06.22 09:19:10 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
   1838 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
   1839     at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
   1840     at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
   1841     at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.6.jar:na]
   1842     at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
   1843 2017.06.22 09:19:10 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
   1844 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
   1845 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
   1846 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
   1847 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
   1848 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
   1849 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1498090742117] stopping ...
   1850 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1498090742117] stopped
   1851 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1498090742117] closing ...
   1852 2017.06.22 09:19:11 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1498090742117] closed
   1853 2017.06.22 09:19:12 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
   1854 <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Any good solutions for this issue?

Comment: Please provide full logs

Comment: Indeed the error message should be available in web.log